# no viewable feature when creating line with ogr in python

Tags: python, ogr, spatialite, sqlite

the python code below produces the expected line shapefile viewable in QGIS

```
import os
from osgeo import ogr

drv=ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
if os.path.exists('test.shp'):
    os.remove('test.shp')
ds=drv.CreateDataSource('test.shp')
lyr=ds.CreateLayer('test',None,ogr.wkbUnknown)
flddef=ogr.FieldDefn('Name',ogr.OFTString)
flddef.SetWidth(32)
lyr.CreateField(flddef)

feat=ogr.Feature(lyr.GetLayerDefn())
feat.SetField('Name','george')
line=ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
line.AddPoint(1116651.439379124, 637392.6969887456)
line.AddPoint(1188804.0108498496, 652655.7409537067)
line.AddPoint(1226730.3625203592, 634155.0816022386)
line.AddPoint(1281307.30760719, 636467.6640211721)
feat.SetGeometry(line)
lyr.CreateFeature(feat)

feat.Destroy()
ds.Destroy()
```

however, when attempting to use the sqlite driver, the database and layer is created with no errors. QGIS can connect to the database and load the layer - though nothing is displayed.

```
drv=ogr.GetDriverByName('SQLite')
if os.path.exists('test.sqlite'):
    os.remove('test.sqlite')
ds=drv.CreateDataSource('test.sqlite',options=['SPATIALITE=yes'])
lyr=ds.CreateLayer('test',None,options=['FORMAT=SPATIALITE'])
flddef=ogr.FieldDefn('Name',ogr.OFTString)
flddef.SetWidth(32)
lyr.CreateField(flddef)

feat=ogr.Feature(lyr.GetLayerDefn())
feat.SetField('Name','george')
line=ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
line.AddPoint(1116651.439379124, 637392.6969887456)
line.AddPoint(1188804.0108498496, 652655.7409537067)
line.AddPoint(1226730.3625203592, 634155.0816022386)
line.AddPoint(1281307.30760719, 636467.6640211721)
feat.SetGeometry(line)
lyr.CreateFeature(feat)

feat.Destroy()
ds.Destroy()
```

on win7, python 2.7.5 (python (x,y) distribution)
BTW - creating a point feature rather than a line works for both cases.
also tried removing the spatialite option from the datasource and layer creation - no change.
am i missing some obvious step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently, this was a geom_type issue, which should be obvious i suppose.

in earlier tests, i would try
lyr=ds.CreateLayer('test',geom_type=ogr.wkbLineString,options=['FORMAT=SPATIALITE'])

which would fail with a geometry constraint error.

finally determined that a different geometry type was needed:
lyr=ds.CreateLayer('test',geom_type=ogr.wkbLineString25D,options=['FORMAT=SPATIALITE'])

now works great. the line displays fine in QGIS and ArcGIS.